# How i can delete img scr in the Javascript code above?

Tags: jquery

```
    function quoteMessage(tekst, poster)
{
       var selected = getSel($('tekst'));
            if(selected.length > 0)
            {
        $('br').remove(); 
                $('tekst').value = $('tekst').value.replace(selected, '[quote=Bericht geplaatst door' + poster + ' "] ' + tekst + ' [/quote] ');
            }
            else
            {
                $('tekst').value += '[quote=Bericht geplaatst door: ' + poster + ' "] ' + tekst + ' [/quote]';
            }
            $('tekst').focus();      
        }
```

How i can delete img scr in the Javascript code above?

Comment: What img? What scr? There's neither in your sample code.

Comment: As far as I can see there isn't even an img in the code above to delete the src from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
$("img").remove();
```

or

img with id

```
$("#img_id").remove();
```

I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for but your question is quite hard to understand

In your case:

```
$("#img [alt='smiley']").remove();
```

Comment: When a user qoute a message i want to delete img scr. Now it is something like: [quote=Bericht geplaatst door: Lord voldemort "] Message <img src="#" alt="smiley"> [/quote] but i want to delete img scr.

Answer (score 1):

If the element is part of the dom you can remove that attribute by,

```
$(<someway to select image>).attr('src',"");
```